# C++ object construction -- direct initialization versus using the '=' operator, are they equivalent?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-initialization, direct-initialization

In C++, are these two styles of initializing a class-object functionally equivalent, or are there some situations where they might have differing semantics and generate different code?

```
SomeClass foo(1,2,3);
```

vs

```
auto foo = SomeClass(1,2,3);
```

Comment: They are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st one is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

The 2nd one is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), in concept `foo` is copy-initialized from the direct-initialized temporary `SomeClass`. (BTW it has nothing to do with `operator=`; it's initialization but not assignment.)

Because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17) they have the same effect exactly, the object is initialized by the appropriate constructor directly.

> In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is
>   a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring [cv-qualification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)) as the
>   variable type:
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> ```

Before C++17 copy elision is an optimization; even the copy/move construction might be omitted the appropriate copy/move constructor has to be usable; if not (e.g. the constructor is marked as `explicit`) the 2nd style won't work while the 1st is fine.

> This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy`/move (since C++11)` constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed: